# How many functions can be defined from $\textrm{A}$ to $\textrm{B}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Help me with the confusion here.

Suppose that set ${A}$ has $4$ elements and set ${B}$ has $2$ elements.

Let $f:{A}\to {B}$ be a function.

If each element from ${A}$ can make $2$ possible choices, shouldn't the number of functions be $2\times 4=8$?

Why does the formula suggest $2^4 = 16$? ($n^m$)

If possible, please give an elaborate answer.

Comment: There are two choices for $f(a_1)$, then two choices for $f(a_2)$, and so on.

Comment: With numbers as small as these, you can enumerate everything explicitly.  Note that every function from $A$ to $B$ can be characterized as a binary  $4-$tuple.  For instance, the $4-$tuple $(0,1,1,0)$ would correspond to $f(a_1)=0, f(a_2)=1, f(a_3)=1,f(a_4)=0$.  You should easily be able to list the $16$ possible binary $4-$tuples

Comment: Try to think about what would happen if B had only one element. If you multiplied the number of elements in set A and B, you would get that the number of possible functions is 4. Which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) is sometimes written as $|A\times B| = |A|\times |B|$.

Alternatively, the Rule of Product as it applies to counting can be phrased as the following:

> If you have a scenario you wish to count the number of possible outcomes and each and every possible outcome can be described uniquely via a sequence of steps where the number of possible results for each step does not depend on previously made choices for earlier steps (*though the choices themselves may vary so long as the quantity of choices does not*), then the total number of outcomes is equal to the product of the number of choices available for each step.

Here, we count the number of functions by breaking into the following steps:

- Pick which element of $B$ is the output of the function for the first element of $A$ (*You have two choices*)
- Pick which element of $B$ is the output of the function for the second element of $A$ (*You have two choices*)
- Pick which element of $B$ is the output of the function for the third element of $A$ (*You have two choices*)
- Pick which element of $B$ is the output of the function for the fourth element of $A$ (*You have two choices*)

**Multiplying** (*not adding*) these number of choices together gives the total count as being $2^4$

---

It is worth noting that some authors choose the very convenient notation of $Y^X$ to denote the set of functions from a domain $X$ to a codomain $Y$ at which point you have the convenient result that $|Y^X| = |Y|^{|X|}$

Answer (score 1):

When you go up the tree of your ancestors you have at each step $2$ choices: the male or the female parent. In this way you have $2$ parents, $4$ grandparents, $8$ great-grandparents, and $16$ great-great-grandparents. The $16=2^4$ persons on the uppermost level represent the $16$ different choice-sequences of length $4$ that are possible. Each such sequene is a function $f:\>\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{{\tt male, female}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we label the elements in set $A$ as $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and the elements in set B as $b_1,b_2$, then it might be easier to see why there are $16$ possible functions. Recall that *by definition*, each element in $A$ should be mapped to one and only one element in set $B$ (otherwise $f$ wouldn't be a function). Since each element of $A$ can be mapped to either $b_1$ or $b_2$, there are
$$
2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 2^4 = 16
$$
possible combinations.